Geometry generator and display setting
I´ve got a problem with geometry generator on QGIS 3.38 when I zoom to maximum scale.
I´ve built a simple geometry generator on a point layer. I click on map, I enter a "radius" value and a circle is shown with x meter around my point. But when I zoom in to the intersect point of two circles and the center point is out of view, the circle are away. Any idea to set these always visible and place a new point on interection of these circles?




Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your Question to contain your most pressing question, and detail what you have attempted to address the problem.

The problem is that the geometry generator draws objects only if the source object falls within the map extents (in your case it is a point). As soon as the object leaves the map boarder - the circles will also disappear.
 <== click to watch
I suggest you use the buffer tool to create polygons or lines around points (they will not disappear). Read more about buffering.
Regarding the second question - how to create points on a buffer intersections - I suggest you to create a separate question, because several problems in one question is a bad practice.
